# Knowledge of value != null

Tags: dart

if I in code write like this, the compiler know what `value` is not null

```
// IT WORKS GOOD
int? value = getIntOrNull();
if (value != null) {
   // now compiler know what value is not null
   int strongInt = value;
} else {
   AssertionError('value should be not null');
}
```

but how I can do it like a `guard` in `swift`? I try to do this by `assert`, but in this case, the compiler does not know what `value` is not null.

```
// IT DOESN'T WORK
int? value = getIntOrNull();
assert(
  value != null,
  'value should be not null',
);

// now compiler does not know what value is not null 
// how I can do the same behaviour like in `if`
int strongInt = value; // error: request `value!`
```

Comment: I  described behavior, in this case, it gives to compiler knowledge about `value is not null`

Comment: exactly. it is on contrast. and in the second example, i asked `how I can do the same behavior like in if` in first example

Comment: in the first case, I should do many nested if { if{ if{ if{}}}}

Answer (score 3):

Asserts are not executed in production mode, so code after the `assert` is not guarded by the assert test. It's possible to get to `int strongInt = value;` with `value` being `null` (by not executing asserts), so the program is not *sound*.
The compiler only promotes if *all* paths to the use go through a test ensuring the promoted type.

So, an `assert(test)` would not promote any more than

```dart
if (assertsEnabled && !(test)) throw AssertionError();
```

where `assertsEnabled` is not known at compile-time.

Comment: thanks for the good advice! but what is "assertsEnabled" for? why is it better than just if (! (test)) throw AssertionError ("message");

Comment: It's "metacode" suggesting how assertions work. In practice, you pass `--enable-asserts` on the command line to the compiler, or choose development/debugging mode in your IDE. There is no global variable telling you whether assertions are enabled (but you can make one as `final bool assertsEnabled = () { var enabled = false; assert(enabled = true); return enabled; }();`.)